# Complex MySQL query with (slightly) different requirements

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a function with a complex MySQL query over multiple tables where I check many conditions such as not-deleted, active, language, date, access rights and so forth. So it already has multiple if-else in it.

Now I need to create another query very similar to the existing one where I query only specific categories with a different order and another one where I search for keywords in the title with a relevance calculation.

You can see two similar queries here: http://pastebin.com/3NY1s1gU and http://pastebin.com/RqpzqWrK
(The table and column names are predefined. I cannot change anything there.)

I don't want to add even more if-else or copy & paste the existing query because it would create a lot of redundant and/or hard-to-maintain code.

Is there a design pattern that approaches this problem?

Comment: Can you extract the common parts into a view and select from that view in both queries?

Comment: I don't have web access to the database, but if views can be created with php and mysql, it should work. Although I haven't used views before.

Answer (score 0):

i am not so much clear about your requirement. i think this will may help you.

you can use first query as inline query as table in your second query but still copy paste is reburied.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but do you mean using views as well? Or what do you mean by "first query as inline query as table"?